# XMLHTTPRequest returns html of page itself

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to practice my AJAX and getting a very strange error.  I wrote a simple program:

```
    <html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id = "ajaxLanding"></div>
    <button onclick = "loadDoc()"></button>
    <script>

        function loadDoc() {
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("ajaxLanding").innerText =
    this.responseText;
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "text1.txt");
  xhttp.send();
}

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I press the button, something very strange happens.  All the HTML on the page appears in the "ajaxLanding" div as text.  Why on Earth would this be?  The "text1.txt" file simply reading "Hello!  I am text1."

Answer (score 0):

Inspect HTTP request header (in Firefox press F12 then click Network tab). You'll see an unexpected GET request (something like "http://yourhost/current_page/text1.txt" instead of "http://yourhost/text1.txt" as probably you want).

Review .htaccess rules or simply put "xhttp.open("GET", "/text1.txt");", if text1.txt is in the root folder of the site.